# Kotlin - How to "lateinit" a var overrided from an interface?

Tags: field, kotlin

I have an interface called `UserManager`

```
interface UserManager {

    var user:User

    /* ... */
}
```

and a class called `UserManagerImpl`, that implements the `UserManager`

```
class UserManagerImpl : UserManager {

    override var user: User // = must provide an User object

    /* ... */
}
```

Here's my problem:

How to allow another class to set an `User` in the `UserManager()` at any time ( *i.e* don't provide an initial `User` object alongside the property declaration and let another class create and provide an `User` instance) ?

**Take in count that**

1. Interfaces cannot have **lateinit** properties
2. I want the `User` to be a non-null value, so no nullable property ( `User?` )
3. I want to use field access instead of declare and use a `setUser(User)` and `getUser()` method in the interface

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is true that "interfaces cannot have **lateinit** properties" but that doesn't prevent implementing classes from using it:

```
interface User

interface UserManager {
    var user: User
}

class UserManagerImpl : UserManager {
    lateinit override var user: User
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val userManager: UserManager = UserManagerImpl()
    userManager.user = object : User {}
    println(userManager.user)
}
```

Prints something like `LateinitKt$main$1@4b1210ee`.

Comment: Excellent @mfulton26 ! I was trying to use `override lateinit var user: User` instead of your approach. :)

Comment: I guess there should be a better diagnostic in the compiler on a wrong order of keywords

Comment: But strangely, I just typed `lateinit override var ...` in IntelliJ, and it popped up a warning to correct it to `override lateinit var`, which also worked